# Learn Ruby on Rails: NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working through Daniel Kehoe's tutorial on rails and have run into a problem that I do not understand and cannot find an answer to online. I get the NoMethodError described in the title of this post when using a flash message with params.

Here is the controller

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

  def process_form
    Rails.logger.debug "DEBUG: params are #{params.inspect}"
    flash[:notice] = "Received request from #{params[:contact][:name]}"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

It works if I remove [:contact] and leave [:name]. If I remove [:name] and leave [:contact] it redirects but doesn't display the name. If I have both [:contact] and [:name] as the controller listing shows I get the NoMethodError and it does not redirect.

Here is my view page

```
<% content_for :title do %>Contact<% end %>
<h3>Contact</h3>
<div class="form">
  <%= form_with( url: contact_path) do |form| %>
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, autofocus: true %>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <%= form.label :email %>
    <%= form.email_field :email %>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <%= form.label 'message' %>
    <%= form.text_area :content, size: '40x5' %>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <%= form.submit 'Submit', class: 'submit' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Here is my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post 'contact', to: 'contacts#process_form'
  root to: 'visitors#new'
end
```

Here is my log when I get the `NoMethodError`:

> Started POST "/contact" 2017-07-23 23:25:11 +0000 Processing by
>   ContactsController#process_form as JS   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"...", "name"=>"Jane Doe",
>   "email"=>"jd@example.com", "content"=>"oiuwroiueroieroiuerw",
>   "commit"=>"Submit"} DEBUG: params are "✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "name"=>"Jane Doe",
>   "email"=>"jd@example.com", "content"=>"oiuwroiueroieroiuerw",
>   "commit"=>"Submit", "controller"=>"contacts",
>   "action"=>"process_form"} permitted: false> Completed 500 Internal
>   Server Error in 3ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `form_with` is the "new standard" in Rails 5.1, I'd continue to use it.

To use `form_with` successfully, you have to use syntax like this:

```
<%= form_with scope: :post, url: posts_path do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :title %>
<% end %>

<%# Will generate %>

<form action="/posts" method="post" data-remote="true">
  <input type="text" name="post[title]">
</form>
```

Or this:

```
<%= form_with model: Post.new do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :title %>
<% end %>

<%# Will generate %>

<form action="/posts" method="post" data-remote="true">
  <input type="text" name="post[title]">
</form>
```

For your particular situation, you should probably be doing something like this:

```
<% content_for :title do %>Contact<% end %>
<h3>Contact</h3>
<div class="form">
  <%= form_with( scope: :contact, url: contact_path) do |form| %>
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, autofocus: true %>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <%= form.label :email %>
    <%= form.email_field :email %>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <%= form.label 'message' %>
    <%= form.text_area :content, size: '40x5' %>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <%= form.submit 'Submit', class: 'submit' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

By doing this, it would modify the name of each input element from being `content`, `email`, `name`, etc to become `contact[content]`, `contact[email]`, `contact[name]`, etc. This would then allow your controller code to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get values as object like `params[:contact][:name]`, you should specify the object to the form helper. Example using `form_for` helper:

```
<%= form_for(@contact) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :name %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is a quick reference to see how to deal with objects in form:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object

If you don't have any idea about how it works, i suggest you to generate the CRUD using the scaffold generator. Example:

```
rails g scaffold Contact name:string email:string
```

This command will generate all files (controller, views) related to the CRUD. So you can use this as reference. It will be already following the Rails convention.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. This worked as long as I put the format in the parens as form_for(:contact, url: contact_path).

Answer (score 1):

Your params looks something like this

```
params{
   :content => 'Words',
   :email => 'example.@gmail.com',
   :name => 'Joey Smith'
}
```

Side note, do you intend 'content' to be 'contact'?

Params is an object and this

```
params[:contact][:name]
```

Would work if your params was structured like:

```
params {
      :contact => {
         :name => 'Joey Smith'
      }
}
```

Which it is not.

Not sure what you are trying to do because I don't see a 'contact'

I would guess that what you want is

```
flash[:notice] = "Received request from #{params[:name]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

`form_with(url: contact_path)` won't add the resource root to your inputs within the form rendered, take a look:

```
<%= form_with(url: contact_path) do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :name %>
  ...
<% end %>

# Will give you
<form action="/contact" method="post" data-remote="true">
  <input type="text" name="name">
</form>
```

And `form_with(model: Model.new)`:

```
<%= form_with(model: Model.new) do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :name %>
<% end %>

# Will give you
<form action="/contact" method="post" data-remote="true">
 <input type="text" name="model[name]">
</form>
```

What you need is to pass the resource to be created, you should have a `new` method in your controller, and there create an instance variable which you can then use in the `model` option of your `form_with`.

See also [Unification of form_for and form_tag into form_with](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_1_release_notes.html#unification-of-form-for-and-form-tag-into-form-with)
.